# Postgres slow limit query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have this simple query in pg

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
select * from email_events 
where act_owner_id = 500
order by date desc
limit 500
```

The first query execution take very long time about 7 seconds.

```
"Limit  (cost=0.43..8792.83 rows=500 width=2311) (actual time=3.064..7282.497 rows=500 loops=1)"
"  ->  Index Scan Backward using email_events_idx_date on email_events  (cost=0.43..233667.36 rows=13288 width=2311) (actual time=3.059..7282.094 rows=500 loops=1)"
"        Filter: (act_owner_id = 500)"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 1053020"
"Total runtime: 7282.818 ms"
```

After the first execution the query i guess is cached and goes in 20-30 ms.

Why the LIMIT is so slow when there is no cache? How can i fix this?

Comment: The table has 2.5 mil rows

Comment: do you have an index on (act_owner_id, date) ?

Comment: Yes i do, even if is order by act_owner_id the result is the same

Comment: Try a composite index on `act_owner_id + date` (in this order).

Comment: How huge is your database aprox? How looks your load on the system? (Thinking of maybe a real huge database with small resources is maybe lagging on I/O on first attempt)

Comment: The database is about 6 GB, it seems on tables bellow 1GB the queries are fast, but for table over 1GB starts to slow down the queries by a lot

Comment: For things like this it's really handy if you show your table and index definitions as `CREATE` statements. Makes it easier to test things locally. Thanks very much for showing your version, SQL, and `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, though.

Answer (score 2):

CLUSTER TABLE on INDEX seems to fix the problem. It seems that after bulk data loading that data is all over the hard drive. CLUSTER table will re-order the data on the hard drive

Comment: Nice to see `CLUSTER`ing on an index being useful for once.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL thinks it will be faster to scan the date-ordered index backwards (i.e. in `DESC` order), reading every row and throwing away the rows that don't have the right `act_owner_id`. It's having to do 1053020 random reads to do this, and backward index scans aren't very fast either.

Try creating an index on `email_events(date DESC, act_owner_id)`. I *think* Pg will be able to do a forward index scan on that and then use the second index term to filter rows, so it shouldn't have to do a heap lookup. Test with `EXPLAIN` and see.

Comment: Not helping... The DB was filled with dummy data generated from me, loaded table by table in bulk...I made CLUSTER on one smaller table, and the problem seems to be fixed for that table. After cleared cache the first time the query is executed in less than 500ms, before CLUSTER used to go up to 20 sec.. will do CLUSTER on the biggest table to see if that will fix the problem